# Adding accept attribute to managed_file field to specify file types client-side

Tags: 7, forms, files

I've got a Drupal 7 file field in a custom form like this:

```
  $form['image_upload'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Image upload'),
    '#description' => t('Upload png images'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#process' => array('file_managed_file_process'),
    '#attributes' => array('accept' => '.png'),
  );
```

As you can see I've added an #attributes array setting the "accept".

1. The accept value doesn't show up in the resulting HTML. I'm surprised it isn't at least set somewhere.
2. If I change the array key from `accept` to `class` then it shows up on the parent div and not on the input element where I expect it.

So, it seems like there are 2 problems to overcome to get to use this feature.

Comment: You may just have found a bug here (or at least undesired behaviour) - the process callback for file_managed (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_managed_file_process/7) doesn't seem to respect the given attributes when building the actual file input element. Let me know if you're unsure of the workaround, I can chuck a code example in when I get home

Comment: I am not aware of a workaround. Please do share :)

Comment: Done @greggles, can't make up my mind whether this is a bug or kinda "makes sense"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not sure if this is a bona fide bug; the file_managed element has several elements inside it, so there's no real way to specify which of those you're targeting with the `#attributes` property.

So in one respect it does make sense that they'd be ignored, because of the ambiguity. But it works for classes, so it makes less sense. Would need a bit more digging to find out why I suspect.

Either way, you can work around it by adding your own process callback to the element:

```
$form['image_upload'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Image upload'),
  '#description' => t('Upload png images'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#process' => array('file_managed_file_process', 'MYMODULE_file_managed_file_process'),
);

function MYMODULE_file_managed_file_process($element) {
  $element['upload']['#attributes']['accept'] = '.jpg';
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For drupal 8:

```
    $form['audio-file'] = [
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => 'select file:',
        '#upload_location' => 'private://',
        '#upload_validators' => [
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('mp3 m4a wav'),
        ],
        '#accept'   =>  '.wav,.mp3,.m4a',
    ];
```

It's all...

Comment: Thx Mate! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For drupal 8, something like this will work, when used in a custom module:

```
function my_module_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context) {
  if (isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] === 'my_field_name') {
    $element['#process'][] = 'app_icon_image_file_validate';
    return $element;
  }
}

function app_icon_image_file_validate(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, &$complete_form) {
  $element['upload']['#attributes']['accept'] = '.svg';
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending Clive answer.

You can use **hook_element_info_alter** to call always the custom process function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 * 
 * @param $type
 */
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  // Custom process managed_file element.
  $type['managed_file']['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_file_managed_file_process';
}

/**
 * @param $element
 * @param $form_state
 * @param $form
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function MYMODULE_file_managed_file_process($element, &$form_state, $form){
  if(isset($element['#upload_attributes'])){
    $element['upload']['#attributes'] = $element['#upload_attributes'];
    unset($element['#upload_attributes']);
  }
  return $element;
}
```

In this way, you can use the custom attribute `#upload_attributes` to give every kind of attributes to the inner `upload` element